# Select max date rows for unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement.

```
            SELECT x.ndc_id
        ,z.attr_val AS trade_name
        ,x.quote_price
        ,x.eff_dt FROM contract_ndc_brg x 
        LEFT JOIN ndc_attr AS z ON z.field_id = 150
        where contract_num_val = (
            SELECT item_name
            FROM [contract]
            WHERE item_id = 184 
            )
```

[image]

Notice there are two rows with the same ndc_id. I want these results but only one result for each `ndc_id` which has the highest `eff_dt`.

I tried adding to the where clause:

```
            SELECT  x.ndc_id
        ,z.attr_val AS trade_name
        ,x.quote_price
        ,x.eff_dt FROM contract_ndc_brg x 
        LEFT JOIN ndc_attr AS z ON z.field_id = 150
        where contract_num_val = (
            SELECT item_name
            FROM [contract]
            WHERE item_id = 184
            ) and  x.eff_dt = (select max(eff_dt) from contract_ndc_brg where contract_num_val = (
            SELECT item_name
            FROM [contract]
            WHERE item_id = 184
            ))
```

I figured out the problem with this is that it is returning the max date for any row.

How can I fix what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Sami Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) is your friend:

```
with q as
(
      SELECT x.ndc_id
        ,z.attr_val AS trade_name
        ,x.quote_price
        ,x.eff_dt
        ,row_number() over (partition by nc_id order by eff_dt desc) rn
        FROM contract_ndc_brg x
        LEFT JOIN ndc_attr AS z ON z.field_id = 150
        where contract_num_val = (
            SELECT item_name
            FROM [contract]
            WHERE item_id = 184 
            )
)
select nc_id, trade_name, quote_price, eff_dt
from q
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I'm getting: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Fixed typo.  FROM started on the same line as eff_dt